# need to understand the use of @TypeDef annotation

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am learning hibernate and want to know the use of @typeDef annotation
I am using

```
> @TypeDef(type="jsonb")
private Emplyoee[] emp;
```

Employee is my model class